# Mapping Ctrl+Shift+<key> to open folder puts focus on sort bar

Tags: windows-7, windows-explorer, autohotkey

I've got several Autohotkey shortcuts to open frequently opened folders.  An example entry:

`^+D:: Run "c:\Development"`

This is a pretty simple script, and I know it's not AutoHotkey's fault, but whenever I enter this command it'll open the folder and put the focus on the sort bar above the files (I have my folders set to display details).  The only ways I know how to get the focus back on the contents of the folder is to either hit enter, which reorders the contents, or to click inside the folder contents with my mouse, which kind of defeats the purpose of navigating to the folder via a hotkey in the first place.

What key combination causes the focus to be put on the sort bar in Windows Explorer, and is there any way to prevent it from doing this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to be a configuration specific issue. On my Windows7  system the filemanager opens with the focus on the files in the directory.

You could ty to jump to the right pane with <kbd>tab</kbd>'s.

Example:

```
^+D::
Run "c:\Development"
Sleep, 400 ; Allow window to open or use winwait
Send, {Tab 4}
Return
```